# Can't edit wp user role editing

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, roles

I am facing a problem with users.

I can't edit their role, I change it, submit, and after the page is refreshed everything goes back to as it was.

I tried to disable ALL plugins. And the problem didn't go..

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

After trying a lot of plugins... I thought it would be better to just do it on PhpMyAdmin.. But wanted to leave that as a last choice... then I came accross a plugin called [Members](http://wordpress.org/plugins/members/)

It's amazing for managing users, and roles as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to back up the database and theme, then re-install WordPress.  You could spend days hunting for the cause or just admit defeat and start a new. :D

Comment: Member plugin did the trick, I am glad I didn't have to do as you suggested :P